# Flow layout with collapsible divs, that maintains row structure

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid layout made with collapsible divs. When they collapse, they leave an empty space underneath, which is automatically filled by the next div (they all have `float: left`). This however does not look good and I would like to maintain the "row structure" without loosing the ability to move the divs around (when the window gets smaller). [JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/GLf7m/)

[image: Problem description]

CSS snippet:

```
.clickable {
     border: 1px dotted black;
     width: 200px;
     float: left;
     height:50px;
     margin-right:20px;
     margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

HTML snippet:

```
<html>
<head><title>Layout test</title></head>
<body>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;3&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;4&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;5&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="clickable">&nbsp;6&nbsp;</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Is there a pure CSS solution? I would like not to mess with JavaScript. I know I can dynamically determine the number of columns and then wrap them into "rows", but I'm not willing to use this solution yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your `float: left` to `display: inline-block`. That's the only change I made to your fiddle, and seems to give the effect you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/GLf7m/2/